# Is it possible to disable input in one field if another is filled?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I want to disable input into fields of a table, if another field contains data in MS Dynamics AX 2012.

**UPDATE 1:**

> If Field1 has input, Field2 and Field3 MUST be EMPTY

|Field1|Field2|Field3| Customer nr | Id|

|---1---|--------|--------| 0000000001| 01

**UPDATE 2:**

Can the system fire an error/warning message, like it does when entering a duplicate value in an ID --> AllowDuplicates: No

-

> Cannot create a record in Table (Table). Table Id: 01. The record
>   already exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, make a method on the table.

In this case (on `ProjTable`) the editing of the name on sub projects is prohibited:

```
void setFieldProperty()
{
    FormObjectSet fds = this.dataSource();
    if (fds)
    {                
        fds.object(fieldNum(ProjTable,Name)).allowEdit(!this.ParentId);
    }
}
```

Then call the method from the form datasource `active` method and from datasource fields `modified` methods on which the critieria depends (in this case `ParentId`).

Response to UPDATE 2:

Take a look on [aosValidateInsert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa660720%28v=ax.50%29.aspx) and [aosValidateUpdate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa657703%28v=ax.50%29.aspx)

Comment: But the table is not meant for use on a form.

Comment: Then what do you mean by "disable input" if not in a form? 
Validation? Consider making you question clearer.