# Enable or disable a field on a forms grid based on another field value in Dynamics AX

Tags: x++, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2009, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

How can we disable and enable fields on a X++ form Dynamics AX ?

[image]

Field1 is an enum with option option1 and option2.

We have below scenarios:

1. If Field1 is option1 then Field2 field should be enabled and Field3 field should be disabled/readonly
2. If Field1 is option2  then Field3 field should be enabled and Field2 should be disabled/readonly

3/ Also, when the form loads, for the existing records the Field3 and Field2 fields should be enabled/readonly based on their current value for Field1

Comment: Did you take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10976083/is-it-possible-to-disable-input-in-one-field-if-another-is-filled?rq=1 ? Or have you tried anything else?

Answer (score 1):

You can override method `active()` on the form's datasource, something like

```
public int active()
{
    FormDataSource fds;
    int ret;

    ret = super();

    fds = this.dataSource();

    fds.object(fieldNum(MyTableName, Field2)).allowEdit(MyDataSourceName.Field1 == option1);
    fds.object(fieldNum(MyTableName, Field3)).allowEdit(MyDataSourceName.Field1 == option2);
    
    return ret;
}
```

That's good enough if `Field1` value cannot be modifed by the user. If it can be modified then it makes sense to create a new method e.g. `setFieldAccess()` with the logic similar to the above, and call this new method both from the datasource `active()` method and from the `modified()` method of the datasource field `Field1`.