# AX code to enable disable menu item button if field value is greater than 0

Tags: axapta

Enable disable Menu item button if lower pane grid value is equal to the view details form value and if the secondary field value is greater than 0 than enable the button else disable it. Microsoft Dynamics AX.

I need to Enable Disable a menu item button on a transfer order form. We have two pane's Upper pane with Invent Transfer Table and Lower pane with Invent Transfer Line. In invent transfer line we have WMSPalletId field and when we view the details it references to the WMS Pallet form. Here we have a customized field INDTareWeight. Now if TareWeight is greater than 0 we need to enable the button else disable. It will be done in active method. But need to know what will be the code for the same. Regards

Comment: Please share more details, demonstrate personal effort to solve the issue and refine your question.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the version of Dynamics AX you are using. Also, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10976083/is-it-possible-to-disable-input-in-one-field-if-another-is-filled